# mat-error not displaying error message angular 5

Tags: angular, material-design, angular5

The problem is the error message is not getting displayed even if i leave the filed blank and move to another field. I am unable to find what i am doing wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated. if i put a breakpoints on onFormValuesChanged() it never hits the breakpoints. i have tried moving the build part of form inside the constructor but don't have any impact. I am not sure if the form's value change event is triggered or not when field value is changed

angular ver : - 5.2.1

HTML Code

```
   <div>
    <form [formGroup]="formPersonalRecord">
    <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlname="firstName">
      <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.firstName.required">
      Please provide name.
      </mat-error>
     </mat-input-container>
     <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
     <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlname="lastName">
     </mat-input-container>
      <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
      <input matInput placeholder="Father's Name" formControlname="fatherName">   
     </mat-input-container>
     <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
      <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlname="email">
       <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.email.required">
        Please provide a email name.
       </mat-error>
     </mat-input-container>
    </form>
    </div>
```

component.cs

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeePersonalRecord } from '../employee/employee-personal-record';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { fuseAnimations } from '../../core/animations';
import { HrService } from '../hr.service';



@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'app-add-employee',
  templateUrl: './add-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-employee.component.scss'],
  animations: fuseAnimations
})

export class AddEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  employeePersonalRecord:   EmployeePersonalRecord     = {} as EmployeePersonalRecord;
  public formPersonalRecord:       FormGroup;
  formErrors: any;
  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder,
    private service: HrService) {
  }

  onFormValuesChanged()
  {
    for ( const field in this.formErrors )
        {
            if ( !this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field) )
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Clear previous errors
            this.formErrors[field] = {};
            // Get the control
            const control = this.formPersonalRecord.get(field);
            if ( control && control.dirty && !control.valid )
            {
                this.formErrors[field] = control.errors;
            }
        }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formPersonalRecord = this.builder.group({
      firstName:              ['', Validators.required],
      lastName:               ['', Validators.required],
      email:                  ['', Validators.required],
      fatherName:             ['', Validators.required],
      dateOfBirth:            ['', Validators.required],
      addressPermanent:       ['', Validators.required],
      addressCurrent:         ['', Validators.required],
      gender:                 ['', Validators.required],
      maritalStatus:          ['', Validators.required],
      religion:               ['', Validators.required],
      cast:                   ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.formErrors = {
      firstName:        {},
      lastName:         {},
      email:            {},
      fatherName:       {},
      dateOfBirth:      {},
      addressPermanent: {},
      addressCurrent:   {},
      gender:           {},
      maritalStatus:    {},
      religion:         {},
      cast:             {}
    };
    this.formPersonalRecord.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.onFormValuesChanged();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have created the stackblitz for the same with minimized code  https://angular-xpc2of-qu3y8q.stackblitz.io

Comment: the stackblitz is broken

Comment: please ignore the first link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcr8bl?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a typo on formControlname. Its formControlName with uppercase N.

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcr8bl-rnayva)

advice :

You should not add *ngIf on mat-error. The whole point of mat error is to avoid doing such thing.

and you should use mat-form-field component to wrap your input

so can you try simply :

```
<form [formGroup]="formPersonalRecord">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
       <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" />
          <mat-error>
                Please provide name.
          </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
...
```

Comment: does not make any difference . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcr8bl-neakdg?file=app/input-overview-example.html

Comment: i updated my answer, you just had a typo in your template

Comment: Man. You are a life saver. You have no idea i was looking at the code from last 3 hrs and thinking...what the hack is going on here... Thanks a lot

Comment: LOL Google is such a troll. Their first and only example here shows `*ngIf`, and I had been coding under the assumption that `*ngIf` is required. The text does say "you can use `*ngIf` should you need to display different error messages," but then the code sample only has one `mat-error`. zzz. Thanks a lot for letting people know `mat-error` can be used standalone under a `mat-form-field`! Gonna save lots of time :) https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages

Comment: **You should not add *ngIf on mat-error. ** That depends on situation. In case if you have multiple error messages for given field (eg required, invalid format, not an email address etc) matinput guarantees to only 1 message be displayed propertly. In such case you need use *ngIF with mat-error

Comment: "you should use mat-form-field component to wrap your input"

Answer (score 13):

`<mat-error>` content is only displayed when control is touched or when form is submitted. `*ngIf` condition can be specified, it is not the issue.
To display `<mat-error>` content for instance when you click on another button than the submit one, simply mark the desired control(s) as touched in the handler of the button:

```js
onMyButtonClick() {
  this.form.get('myControl').markAsTouched();
  ...
}
```

Another way to display a message under the control without any contrainst linked to Angular validity management, is to use `<mat-hint>` instead of `<mat-error>`

Comment: For me, it was **not enough to do markAsTouched() the whole form** I had to do it specifically on the fields where mat-error needed to be triggered, just like in this answer

Answer (score 9):

This might be late but I'm having the same issue and found out that I have to bind my input [formControl] to the formGroup first before getting the formControl like so :

```
<form [formGroup]="formPersonalRecord">

 <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
   <input matInput placeholder="First Name" [formControl]="formPersonalRecord.get('firstName')">
   <mat-error *ngIf="formPersonalRecord.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
      Please provide name.
   </mat-error>
 </mat-input-container>
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, `mat-error` does not display until either the control is touched (blurred), or the form is submitted.

Comment: That's what I don't like. I need to have the error show up on the keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any ErrorStateMatcher?
You should use it.

Here is the stackblitz of the material doc, with an input that uses errorstatematcher : https://stackblitz.com/angular/voepaombnnb

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with diplaying message in mat-error(
And "updateValueAndValidity" fixed this problem)
In this exemplar, I show async error message in mat-error.

```
    onSubmit() {
    this.formSub = this.authenticationService
      .forgotPassword(this.resetForm.get('email').value).subscribe(
        next => {

        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.resetForm.get('email').updateValueAndValidity();
          if (error[0] === 'USER_NOT_FOUND') {
            const passwordForm = this.resetForm.get('email');
            if (passwordForm) {
              passwordForm.setErrors({
                serverError: 'Email not found!'
              });
            }
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use:

```
updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true })
```

If you use `onlySelf = true`, you don't need to put `"markAsTouched"` in your control and works with every scenario!