# Angular Mat Form Input not throwing error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a simple text input field, my **checkUrlFormat()** function is working good at .ts file but here it is showing nothing, it is like even not checking.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Enter link here</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputText">
    <mat-error *ngIf="checkUrlFormat()">
        Please enter the link in correct format
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

and checkUrlFormat() is:

```
checkUrlFormat() {
    const pattern = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
    if (pattern.test(this.inputText)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: show `checkUrlFormat`

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly in https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview there is a text unput with instant error mesage

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443397/mat-error-not-displaying-error-message-angular-5?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: its for url format. if i put mat-error tag outside of  mat-form-field tags it is working but it is starting to work directly instead of being null at beginning. but othervise (like in example) it is not working